# Laravel Log useFiles method is making Log write in multiple files

Tags: php, laravel, logging, monolog, laravel-facade

I am using **Laravel Log Facade** in my app. And I have several services like Mandrill, Twilio, Stripe, etc., that need to be logged in separate file. But when I use Log::useFiles() to set separate file for one of the service wrapper class, like this:

```
Class Mailer
{
    static function init()
    {
        Log::useFiles(storage_path('logs/mandrill-'.date("Y-m-d").'.log'));
    }

    static function send()
    {
        // some code here...

        Log::error("Email not sent");
    }
}
```

And I am ending up with log being written in both Laravel log file, and this Mandrill log file.

Is there a way to tell Log to write logs only in one file?

It's generally strange that it does that, because when I use directly **Monolog**, it writes only in one file, as it should. As far as I know Log Facade is using Monolog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind that if you change the log handlers in your **Mailer** class you'll change them for the whole application.

Secondly, the reason that after your changes you get logs written to 2 files is that **useFiles()** does not overwrite the default **log handler** but adds a new handler to the handlers that **Monolog** will use. Therefore, you just add a second handler to the list and both of them handle the log message by saving them into different files.

Thirdly, Laravel's **Log** facade does not provide a way to replace the default handler - if you want to use it you need to use **Monolog** directly. You can access it by calling **Log::getMonolog()**.

Comment: Well that's bad. Can't find a reason why would I keep putting handlers on the pile for the whole app. Back to Monolog than

Comment: Is there a way to remove second log handler after I wrote to log all I needed?

Comment: more info here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32552639/3784481)
note that by passing false value as third argument you can disable bubbling up the stack, therefore you can controller what's in different log files